# AAD auth and cookie name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am using ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC.

My startup adds AddAuthentication

I want to be able to configure my cookie which stores the AAD token.
I tried to add this code below. 
But when i run my app in Chrome, I do not see the cookie name in dev tools. Any ideas?

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MeAPP";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the cookie name by :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieName";
});
```

Comment: good that i see the cookie. but now my logout code has a error :
No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Cookies

HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

I still want aad login ,is a cookie required for AAD auth?

Comment: Not meet the problem , the aad auth itself use cookie authentication in client app

Comment: Hey @NanYu Can you help me with a similar question. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348505/changing-the-domain-name-for-aad-auth-with-openidconnect-for-multi-node-multi-ge